# Creating custom radio button helper in application_helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create custom radiobuttons via Bootstrap.
I did it, but I want to add this control in application_helper.

My current solution

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
      <% @engines2.each do |e| %>
        <button type="button" class="btn <%= @car.engine_id == "#{e.id}".to_i ? 'active' : '' %>" data-toggle="button" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('car_input_engine_id').value='<%= "#{e.id}" %>'">
            <%= "#{e.name}" %>
        </button>
      <% end %>
      <input type="hidden" id="car_input_engine_id" name="car[input_engine_id]" value="<%= @car.engine_id %>" />
 </div>
```

### Desired use

```
<%= form_for @car, :method => "post" do |f| %>
  <%= checkbox_bootstrap_tag(@engines2, @car.engine_id) %>
    <%= f.submit "Test Post", :class => "btn btn-inverse" %>
<% end %>
```

### Helper

```
 def checkbox_bootstrap_tag(engines, car_engine_id)   
    content_tag :div, :class=>"btn-group", "data-toggle"=>"buttons-radio" do
      engines.each do |e|
        content_tag :button, :type => :button,
        :class=>'btn #{car_engine_id == #{e.id}.to_i ? "active" : ""}',
        "data-toggle"=>"button", 
        :onclick=>"javascript:document.getElementById('car_input_engine_id').value=#{e.id}" do
           e.name       
        end
      end
      content_tag :input, :type => :hidden, :id=>"car_input_engine_id", :name=>"car[input_engine_id]", :value=>car_engine_id
    end
  end
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this fragment:

```
  engines.each do |e|
    ...
  end
```

It preforms something, but its result is going away, as there's one more line after it:

```
content_tag :input, :type => :hidden, :id=>"car_input_engine_id", :name=>"car[input_engine_id]", :value=>car_engine_id
```

So you have to concatenate both results: of `engines.each ...` and this line's result.

And I think you were planing to make `engines.map` instead `engines.each`: to get an array of `button`-tags.

Then you have to fix this line:

```
:class=>'btn #{car_engine_id == #{e.id}.to_i ? "active" : ""}',
```

You're trying to perform interpolation (`#{..}`) but you wrapped it in single quotes `'..'`. You can use `%[ ... ]` (where `[` is a matter of preferences, you can use `%{...}` or other brackets if you want) if you have a string with mixed single/double quotes.

Also `content_tag` for `input` isn't suitable. What content the `input` tag has to have? Right, no content at all! So use simple `tag` helper instead.

So, here's what I got:

```
def checkbox_bootstrap_tag(engines, car_engine_id)   
  content_tag :div, :class=>"btn-group", "data-toggle"=>"buttons-radio" do
    engines_html = engines.map do |e|
        content_tag :button, 
          :type => :button,
          :class=> %[btn #{car_engine_id == e.id ? "active" : ""}], 
          :data => {:toggle => "button"},
          :onclick=> "javascript:document.getElementById('car_input_engine_id').value=#{e.id}" do
            e.name       
        end
      end
    safe_join(engines_html) +
      tag(:input, :type => :hidden, :id=>"car_input_engine_id", :name=>"car[input_engine_id]", :value=>car_engine_id)
  end
 end
```

Note the usage of `safe_join`: this helper is useful for merging array elements with HTML markup (to not escape them before output).

Also `:data => {:toggle => "button"},` part must tell you that Rails helpers are aware of this attribute.