# I want to use bootstrap checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) checkboxes.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Right</button>
</div>
```

How do I integrate it into a [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) application?

I would like to use them in a form. Specifically, how can I send and catch the selected data?

**UPDATE**:

I know how to use checkboxes in Rails. I don't understand how can I [set their style via bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons).

Checkbox is - `<input type="checkbox">Simple</input>`

Bootstrap checkbox is `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Bootstrap</button>`

**UPDATE 2**:

As example, see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949250/bootstrap-radoibuttons-in-rails) about radio buttons.

Comment: Check out the code example, you can included classes as I show to achieve desired stylings.

Answer (score 4):

For example you can delete an item like this:

```
<p>Delete item <%= asset.check_box :_destroy %></p>
```

Or it's even easier if you use the simple_form gem, for example if you have a boolean attribute in your model checkboxes are the default:

```
<%= f.input :agreement %>
```

Or you can force checkboxes like this:

```
<%= f.foobar, :as => :check_boxes %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/anjlab/bootstrap-rails) to incorporate to bootstrap css and javascript libraries into you application.  There are several flavors of rails bootstrap but I personally use this one because it is written in SASS (more commonly used with rails than LESS).

You have some issues with how you approaching this as its seems you have three options and only one of which I'd assume should be selected (for which I recommend using a `select` tag) and you are using buttons not checkboxes... but to integrate checkboxes into you application, rails indeed offers a methods, an example in a `form_for` is as follows:

```
- form_for @something_with_a_postion do |something|     
  = something.label 'Left'
  = something.check_box 'position', 'left', {class: 'whatever_classes_for_bootstrap_needed'}
  = something.label 'Middle'
  = something.check_box 'position', 'middle', {class: 'whatever_classes_for_bootstrap_needed'}
  = something.label 'Right'
  = something.check_box 'position', 'right', {class: 'whatever_classes_for_bootstrap_needed'}
```

You can find more on `form_for` and `check_box` [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box).

I also refer you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425176/in-rails-how-to-handle-multiple-checked-checkboxes-just-split-on-the-or).  As well, [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes) is a RailsCast pertaining to checkboxes.